# Remove particular index range from bytearray and then recombine c#

Tags: c#, arraylist, arrays, copyonwritearraylist

I have a requirement where I have large amount of data in bytearray. I want to select 39998 data and skip the 39999,40000.40001,40002 index and then again select after this 39998 data and skip 39999,40000.40001,40002.

So my requirement is that
 I need total byte array of size 39998*12=479976

I have tried this solution

```
for (int i = 1; i < 13; i++)
{
    list.RemoveAt(39999 * i);
    list.RemoveAt((39999 * i) + 1);
    list.RemoveAt((39999 * i) + 2);
    list.RemoveAt((39999 * i) + 3);
}
```

But it shift the list.

I need to select data from 1 to 39998 skip 4 byte and then select 39998 and skip 4 byte and so on upto 12 times. and then recombine bytearray. Actually If we are using list it shift the indexing so in second times It occur problem(remove the other index). So If other suggestion you have please let me know

Comment: I think you'd want to start `i` at 13 and decrement to 1 so that your offsets are not effected by the removes in previous loops.

Comment: I have a requirement where I need to select data from 1 to 39998 skip 4 byte and then select 39998 and skip 4 byte and so on upto 12 times. and then recombine bytearray. Actually If we are using list it shift the indexing so in second times It occur problem(remove the other index). So If other suggestion you have please let me know

Comment: I think you could just subtract 4 times `i - 1` to account for the removed items in previous loops.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
for (int i = 12; i > 0; i--)
{
  list.RemoveAt((39999 * i) + 3);
  list.RemoveAt((39999 * i) + 2);
  list.RemoveAt((39999 * i) + 1);
  list.RemoveAt(39999 * i);
}
```

Comment: Hi @Graham The Bytearray size is dynamic , I have a requirement where I need to select data from 1 to 39998 skip 4 byte and then select 39998 and skip 4 byte and so on upto 12 times.
and then recombine bytearray. Actually If we are using list it shift the indexing so in second times It occur problem(remove the other index).
So If other suggestion you have please let me know.

Comment: In that case I'm afraid it is not clear what you want. Maybe `array.Where((x,i) => i % 40002 < 39998).ToArray()` allows for different size arrays?

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the problem correctly would something like this work?

```
int iterations = 12;
var newList = new List<byte>();

for(int i = 0; i < iterations; i++)
{
    newList.AddRange(list.Skip(40002 * i).Take(39998));
}

var result = newList.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

```
int take = 39998;
int skip = 4;

int iterationBatch = take + skip;
int finalAmount = take * 12;

var yourNewArray = yourOldArray
    .GroupBatch(iterationBatch)
    .SelectMany(x => x.Take(take))
    .Take(finalAmount)
    .ToArray();
```

Using an extension method looking like:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> GroupBatch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, int batchSize)
{
    int count = enumerable.Count();
    for (int taken = 0; taken < count ; taken += batchSize)
    {
        yield return enumerable.Skip(taken).Take(batchSize);
    }
}
```

I've not tested it thoroughly though, but you get the general idea of it...